# GraphicsMagick: toBuffer() Stream yields empty buffer

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I am trying to read a file into a buffer, resize it and then write it to disk using the following example code:

```
function processImage(data) {
gm(data, 'test.jpg')
    .resize('300x300')
  .background('white')
  .flatten()
  .setFormat('jpg')
  .toBuffer(function(err, buffer) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        fs.writeFile('asd.jpg', buffer);
    }
  });
}
```

However, this generates an error `Error: Stream yields empty buffer`. I have played around, used imageMagick and graphicsMagick, still the same.

If i substitute
`toBuffer(...`
with
`write('asd.jpg', function(err) ...`

it actually writes a proper file.

**EDIT** While writing this question I found the solution, see reply

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`setFormat('jpg')`
caused the problems. Changing it to
`setFormat('jpeg')` solved it.

Comment: Can also add extension as an argument .toBuffer('jpeg', (error, buffer) => to avoid the setFormat line.

Answer (score 16):

Was facing the same problem, in my case: install the graphicsmagick binary.

`sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick`

Comment: Same here. `brew install graphicsmagick` on Mac (if you've got Homebrew installed)

Answer (score 8):

> Stream yields empty buffer

This indicates a general error of graphiksmagick. 
Here are some probable causes:

1. **Missing Installation**:  you did not install graphicsmagick or imagemagick correctly. Make sure you installed both and
2. **Invalid Parameter**: remove all parameters until it works. jpg instead of jpeg is a common mistake
3. **Wrong library** You made use of graphicmagick but wanted to use imagemagick? (e.g. for webp conversion).  Add imageMagick configuration:

```html
const gm = require('gm').subClass({imageMagick: true});
```

Feel free to add more ideas as comment.

Comment: The Missing Installation point solved it for me—I didn't read the ReadMe and didn't realise that you had to also have GraphicsMagick installed separately. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I also stumbled upon this error. For me the solution was to increase the allowed memory from 128Mb to 256Mb. I noticed the process needed 137Mb in order to succeed.

Comment: How do you do that? Was this the node process or the imagemagick process?

Comment: It was the lambda process itself.

Answer (score 1):

> Error: Stream yields empty buffer

For me the solution of the error was to **install both `graphicsmagick` and `imagemagick`**.

Maybe it is because I use the app in `node-alpine` container and I want to use only `graphicsmagick` functionality of `gm`.