# Stream yields empty buffer

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

I used GraphicsMagick for node but got the error "Stream yields empty buffer"

```
import gm from 'gm';    

gm(buffer).resize(200, 200).setFormat('jpeg') .toBuffer( function (err, buf) {
const data = {
  Key: imagePath,
  Body: buf,
  ContentEncoding: 'base64',
  ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
};
...
some code to upload to AWS S3
});
```

This is my docker config

```
FROM node:10.16-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache bash graphicsmagick
```

I expected to have the buffer after used gm and push file to AWS S3.
Would anyone can help me solved this issue?
Thank you so much.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35433249/graphicsmagick-tobuffer-stream-yields-empty-buffer . check if you find ur answer here